# Error ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID with wildcard certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard

I am quite a newbie to the subject of certificates.

The case is that I am trying to install a wildcart certificate for a server (where I will later host a REST API), but I cannot correctly configure xampp to get a secure ssl connection

For more complication, the server has other open ports different from the typical 80 and 443

This is my https-ssl.conf file configuration:

```
Listen 6998

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES

SSLHonorCipherOrder on 

SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

SSLSessionCache "shmcb:C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:6998>

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
ServerName MY_iP:6998
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile "c:/xampp/apache/conf/certificate/MY_CERTIFICATE_FILE.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/xampp/apache/conf/certificate/MY_CERTIFICATE_FILE.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile "c:/xampp/apache/conf/certificate/MY_CERTIFICATE_FILE.ca-bundle"

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

The port 6998 is open. I have checked it.
And the certificate is for: *.appinovation.com

With this configuration, i always obtain this error:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

I have tried changing the servername configuration to MY_IP.appinnovation.com:6998, MY_iP:6998... but i think there is some other errors that i don't find

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, can you share your certificate's common name and Subject Alternative Name(s)? And also the domain you used. Eg. appinovation.com, abc.appinovation.com or something_else.appinovation.com

I guess, your certificate's common name is `*.appinovation.com` and Subject Alternative Name is `*.appinovation.com`. And you use `appinovation.com`.

If my guesses are correct, the problem is, **Your Cerificate Is Not Suitable For Your REST API**.

You need to use a new certificate. And make sure your Common Name and Subject Alternative Name is set to the domain you used. (A question asked above.)

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Indeed, your assumptions are correct. The common name of my certificate is * .appinnova.com, and the alternative subject is also * .appinnova.com and .appinnova.com... but how can i set the common name and subject alternativa name?

Comment: Is your certificate self-signed? Or purchase from a trusted CA?

Comment: purchase from a trusted CA (Sectigo)

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need to re-purchase from Sectigo, and the most important note is, purchase a single domain cert for appinovation.com, not wildcard.

Comment: If you need free cert, you can use LetsEncrypt by requesting it through Certbot.

Comment: I know that purchasing a wildcard certificate is quite expensive, but it is not suitable for your need.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try the LetsEncrypt certificate and see if I can get it to work!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228881/discussion-between-choo-yj-and-mimmetico).